# libwebviewchromium.so error in my last (and first) android 4.4.4 build

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I'm getting this error on my latest (and first) `AOSPA` build for `lt01wifi`.

It happens when I try to open Browser but it crashes before it opens.

**Error Log:**

```
I/LibraryLoader( 5999): Loading: webviewchromium
E/ActivityThread( 5999): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
E/dalvikvm( 5999): dlopen("/system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so") failed: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH in "libwebviewchromium.so" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)
E/WebViewFactory( 5999): error instantiating provider
E/WebViewFactory( 5999): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load WebView
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is the `.so` file itself that is the problem.

It was built with `--hash-style=gnu`, which is not supported in Android platform.

You should build your `.so` file again.
And [this link](http://duanple.blog.163.com/blog/static/7097176720111141085197/) could be helpful.